# Is there a built-in function like setw() in java? If not how can I format this?

Tags: java, string, format

How can I format strings and numbers(double,int etc)?

I have tried %-10s and %10.2f

```
String c1="Java";
String c2="Visual Basic";

        System.out.printf("%-30s %d \tPass\n",c1,100);
        System.out.printf("%-30s %d \tFail\n",c2,20);
```

I expect the output should be

```
Java                          100   Pass
Visual Basic                   20   Fail
```

but the actual output is

```
Java                           100  Pass
Visual Basic                       20  Fail
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://ideone.com/DhNQXm), other than that you haven't done anything to justify the numbers. But the 20 definitely lines up with the 100.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't produce the output you've said it does, it produces:

```
Java                           100  Pass
Visual Basic                   20   Fail
```

If the problem is that the 20 is aligned with the left side of the 100 rather than the right, just add an appropriate width to your output of the number (for instance, `%3d`):

```
String c1="Java";
String c2="Visual Basic";

System.out.printf("%-30s %3d \tPass\n", c1, 100);
System.out.printf("%-30s %3d \tFail\n", c2, 20);
```

That outputs:

```
Java                           100  Pass
Visual Basic                    20  Fail
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/ZTfubx)